# Accessing other table column data gives null result

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have several table and 1 of those table is main table where all raw data contained:

[image]

This is the result after executing CTE4.

```
CTE4 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        roadname,
        SUM(CASE WHEN roadCrossSection1 IS NOT NULL THEN roadLength END) AS roadLength,
        ISNULL(AVG(CASE WHEN elevationDifference <= 0 THEN elevationDifference END),0) AS eglAvgDepth,
        ISNULL(AVG(CASE WHEN elevationDifference > 0 THEN elevationDifference END),0) AS pglAvgDepth,
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN elevationDifference <= 0 THEN roadLength END),0) AS eglLength,
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN elevationDifference > 0 THEN roadLength END),0) AS pglLength,
        MAX(roadCrossSection1) roadCrossSection1
    FROM 
        CTE3
    GROUP BY 
        roadName
)
-----final view
SELECT *
FROM CTE4
ORDER BY roadName
```

As soon as I add another CTE (CTE5), it resulted in an unexpected way.

[image]

This is the table `dbo.roadCrossSection`:

[image]

After running this script, I expect that roadCrossSection1 type2A will be equal to CW1=6

```
CTE5 AS (
SELECT roadName,roadLength,
IIF(C.roadCrossSection1=R.crossSection,R.CW,0) as CW1

FROM CTE4 AS C LEFT JOIN dbo.roadCrossSection AS R
ON C.roadName=R.crossSection
)


SELECT *
FROM CTE5
ORDER BY roadName
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Your join condition looks wrong, you have `LEFT JOIN dbo.roadCrossSection AS R ON C.roadName=R.crossSection`, I expect you want `ON C.roadCrossSection1=R.crossSection`.

Comment: @GarethD i have several C.roadCrossSection (roadCrossSection1, roadCrossSection2,roadCrossSection3,roadCrossSection4.......). Something like FROM CTE4 AS C LEFT JOIN dbo.roadCrossSection AS R
ON C.roadCrossSection1=R.crossSection,
ON C.roadCrossSection2=R.crossSection,
ON C.roadCrossSection3=R.crossSection...

Answer (score 0):

If we concentrate on a single row from your ouput of CTE4:

```
Roadname    RoadLength  eglAvgtDepth    pglAvgDepth     eglLength   pglLength   roadCrossSection1
p3-AL-2137  103.997     -0.202500       0.170000        60.996      43.001      2A
```

then look at your join in CTE5:

```
CTE5 AS (
SELECT roadName,roadLength,
IIF(C.roadCrossSection1=R.crossSection,R.CW,0) as CW1

FROM CTE4 AS C LEFT JOIN dbo.roadCrossSection AS R
ON C.roadName=R.crossSection  -- <-- THIS JOIN HERE!!!
)
```

So you are looking for a row in `dbo.roadCrossSection` where the value for `crossSection` is `p3-AL-2137` (Roadname from CTE4).

Based on the screenshot you posted there are now rows in  `dbo.roadCrossSection` where `crossSection = 'p3-AL-2137'`, therefore no record is being returned from `dbo.roadCrossSection`.

There is however a row in the table where the value is `2A` which correspondends with the `roadCrossSection1` column, rather than the `roadName` column. If you change your join to the following, then you should get rows returned:

```
    ON C.roadCrossSection1=R.crossSection
```

Once your join is correct, your `IIF` expression becomes redundant and can be replaced with `ISNULL`:

```
CTE5 AS (
SELECT roadName,roadLength, ISNULL(R.CW,0) as CW1
FROM CTE4 AS C LEFT JOIN dbo.roadCrossSection AS R
    ON C.roadCrossSection1=R.crossSection  
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE5
ORDER BY roadName;
```